# How to fix TPM in Redhat Linux? RedHat Linux hang on first time to boot after installing

Tags: linux, redhat, boot

I am trying to install Redhat Enterprise Linux 64x version 6.3 or 6.4, on a server that has two Xenon CPU and RAID 1 with two 2TB HDD.
Installation will go very well and because I will use that server as multiple usage I am trying to select all optional packages so that later during installation of applications I will not have any problem. I did the same way of installation in my Virtual Machine (VM Ware) and it is working properly but now that I want to install on the actual server I have a problem.
After installation is finished, I reboot the server but server cannot boot properly. It stop in the screen that shows TPM error. I write down everything that I can see on the screen.

Can you help me how to solve this problem? Maybe there is a package that I must not install and I am installing? I tried not to install any package that has a name TPM in it.

Here is what I see in the screen:

TBOOT: TPM: tpm_validate_locality timeout
TBOOT: TPM is not available
TBOOT: TPM: tmp_validate_locality timeout
TBOOT: TPM: Locality 0 is not open
TBOOT: TPM: write nv 20000002, offset 0000000, 0000004 bytes, return = 00000009
TBOOT: Error: write TPM error: 0x9.
TBOOT: TPM not ready
TBOOT: no LCP module found
TBOOT: Error: ELF magic number is not matched
TBOOT: assuming kernel is Linux format
TBOOT: Initrd from 0x7b58d000 to 0x7e2fa000
TBOOT: Kernel (protected mode) from 0x1000000 to 0x13d7630
TBOOT: Kernel (real mode) from 0x88700 to 0x8bd00
TBOOT: transfering control to kernel @0x1000000...

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

After all my search I found out that in Redhat 6 there is a problem tboot and best way to fix it is to remove tboot package (it is located in System Base>Base>tboot.6)

For more info about tboot you can check these links:
[enter link description here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.3_Technical_Notes/tboot.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is regarding the 'trusted boot' scheme. So, update your packages from the online repositories (which you are ALSO paying for access to), and be sure to grab the latest tboot package, or go into your BIOS, and set it to boot in 'legacy' mode, which lets you get around the 'trusted boot' scheme.(copied)

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-enterprise-47/how-to-fix-tpm-error-in-redhat-linux-4175476145/